# How to represent reverse loop in mathematics

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a loop as follows:

```
while(n > 0)
{
    p = p_this_minus_one * p_this;
    p_minus_one = p;
    n--;
}
```

Using the aforementioned code I want to represent the logic as follows:

$P = (P_{i-1} * P_i) * (P_{i-2} * P_{i-1}) * (P_{i-3} * P_{i-2})......\text{ till }(i-N) > 0$

Can someone let me know how I can represent the aforementioned formula in mathematics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pi notation, the multiplicative analogue of Sigma notation.  In this case it sounds like you’re trying to expres something like $\Pi_{n=0}^{i-1} P_{i-(n+1)}P_{i-n}$.